# MySQL where statement based on if

Tags: mysql, if-statement, where-clause

Hi I'm making an MySQL statement from the following logic.

```
Select * from content 
if(description=='educational')
where serial like '%EDU2015%'
else where serial like '%NOVEL2015%'
```

The logic is simply as, if the description column is educational, the filter should have the string "EDU2015. Else, it should filter with the serial of "NOVEL2015"

I'm not sure if im using the way to use the IF statement in mysql but i dont know where to place the where statements from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: try case :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: try case and divide your logic into cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CASE expression like this:

```
SELECT * FROM content
WHERE serial like CASE WHEN description = 'educational'
                       THEN '%EDU2015%'
                       ELSE '%NOVEL2015%'
                  END
```

Note that when you compare values, a single equal sign is required and not two.

EDIT: If you want to filter on different columns based on a condition, you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM content
WHERE (description = 'educational' and  serial like '%EDU2015%')
    OR(description <> 'educational' and id>100)
```

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto Actually CASE is ANSI SQL, so I think all versions support it

Comment: Thanks! it works. But what if i need a different filter for different condition? 
Let's say.

Select * from content
if(description=='educational')
where serial like '%EDU2015%'
else where id >100

Answer (score 5):

You can use `IF` in WHERE block like that:

```
Select * 
from content 
where serial like IF(description = 'educational','%EDU2015%','%NOVEL2015%');
```

Alternatively you can choose `CASE WHEN` expression like @sagi stated.

[image]

```
mysql> SELECT IF(1>3,'true','false');
+------------------------+
| IF(1>3,'true','false') |
+------------------------+
| false                  | 
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works too

```
Select * from content 
where if(description = 'educational', serial like '%EDU2015%', serial like '%NOVEL2015%');
```